# How to mock PATCH methods of WebAPI using MS Unit?

Tags: json, api, unit-testing, asp.net-core, patch

I have the following PATCH method for which I am writing Unit Tests.

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<QuoteDraft> patch) {
    Global.AccessToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    var draft = new QuoteDraft();
    var json = string.Empty;
    try {
        draft = quoteDraftRepository.GetQuoteDraftById(id);
        if (draft == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Draft quote not found for id {id}");
        }
        QuoteDraft quoteDraft = null;
        foreach (var item in patch.Operations) {
            json = Convert.ToString(item.value);
            var lineItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LineItem>(json);
                    quoteDraft = AddLineItem(draft, lineItem);
        }

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new QuoteDraftResponse {
            Message = messageHandler.GetMessage(MessageType.All),
            QuoteDraft = quoteDraft
        });
    }
```

Below is my unit test method:

```
[testmethod]
public void patchtestmethod()
{
    var jsonobject = new jsonpatchdocument<quotedraft>();
    var quotedraft = new quotedraft
    {
        market = "noo",
        program = "ils",
        brochure = "2019",
        season = "v1",
        currency = "nok",
        totalprice = 100,
    };

    var value = jsonconvert.serializeobject(quotedraft);
    jsonobject.add("/lineitem/-", value);
    quotecontroller.patch(it.isany<guid>(), jsonobject);
}
```

I am getting the error as shown in below screenshot:

[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqSMC.png)

The json patch has to look something like this.

```
   op: 'add',
    path: '/lineItem/-',
    value: {
      destination: this.props.result.destination.code,
      currency: this.props.result.currency.code,
      sku: getSku(this.props.result.course.code, this.props.result.destination.code),
      unitType: this.props.result.course.unitType,
      startDate: format(this.props.result.startDate),
      endDate: this.props.result.endDate,
      quantity: this.props.result.numberOfWeeks.id,
      category: 'Course',
      language: 'NO',
      departurePoint: this.props.result.departure ? this.props.result.departure.code : null,
      description: this.props.result.course.description
    },
```

Kindly let me know what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: You should add the actual code instead of images of code.

Comment: Sure Rakesh! I will take care of this next time :)

Comment: What is the full defination for `QuoteDraft`? Based on your expected `json`, I assume you have a collection `lineItem` property.

Answer (score 2):

For `jsonobject.Add`, it accpets `Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> path` which is used to define the path for this operation.

1. Model.cs

   ```
   public class QuoteDraft
   {
       public string Market { get; set; }
       public string Program
       {
           get; set;
       }
       public List<LineItem> LineItem { get; set; }
   }
   public class LineItem
   {
       public string Destination { get; set; }
       public string Sku { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Code

   ```
   var jsonobject = new JsonPatchDocument<QuoteDraft>();
   var quotedraft = new QuoteDraft
   {
       Market = "noo",
       Program = "ils"
   };
   var lineItem = new LineItem
   {
       Destination = "D",
       Sku = "S"
   };
   jsonobject.Add(q => q, quotedraft);
   jsonobject.Add(q => q.LineItem, lineItem);
   var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonobject);
   ```